# Using rtrim on DOCUMENT_ROOT give unexpected result

Tags: php, replace, trim

I am trying to remove any trailing slash from `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/\\')
```

But its adding `%5C`  after using `rtrim`:

```
E:%5Cwamp%5Cwww%5Ctestfolder
```

Also I replace all slash with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` before using `rtrim`, but same thing happen.

Please tell me why its happening ?

Comment: try using urldecode($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) and then do your rtrim

Answer (score 1):

The `%5C` is from URL encoding. The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value is not URL-encoded, so perhaps you are urlencoding the output when you send it to your browser?

`rtrim` only trims the end of the string, and your example output shows that no slash is suffixed to the string - it appears `rtrim` has done its job.

Please post your whole code for a more detailed look.